# How to Configure CORS for a Streamlit App on Heroku When Embedded in an Iframe?

Tags: heroku, iframe, cors, streamlit

I'm embedding a Streamlit app hosted on Heroku in an iframe in my Next.js app. The Streamlit app has a CSV upload feature, which works fine when accessed directly but throws a

```js
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
```

when used through the iframe (in another domain).

This seems to be a CORS issue. I'm looking for guidance on how to configure CORS on Heroku to allow requests from my Next.js app's domain.

I checked these topics without luck:

- [File Uploader 403 Error When Embedding Streamlit App in Iframe](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/file-uploader-403-error-when-embedding-streamlit-app-in-iframe/24109)
- [Embedded Streamlit App as Iframe: XMLHttpRequest and CORS Errors](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/embedded-streamlit-app-as-iframe-xmlhttprequest-and-cors-errors/53380)
- [Issue with Receiving postMessage Events in a Streamlit App Embedded in a Next.js Iframe](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/issue-with-receiving-postmessage-events-in-a-streamlit-app-embedded-in-a-next-js-iframe/61601)

Has anyone tackled this or have any advice?

Comment: Recently found that in flask and other frameworks they explicitly have CORS packages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the CORS issue by adjusting the `setup.sh` script. I had only set `enableCORS = false`, but you must disable XSRF protection also. Here's the updated `setup.sh` file that solved the problem:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/

echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
port = \$PORT\n\
enableXsrfProtection=false\n\
enableCORS = false\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

By setting both `enableXsrfProtection` and `enableCORS` to false, I eliminated the upload issue. Please note that disabling these features might have implications for your application's security.

For anyone facing similar issues, this approach was effective for me. There's also a related discussion on [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/axioserror-request-failed-with-status-code-403/38112) that might provide additional insights.